# Невозможно преобразовать const char* в char*

Tags: c++, строки, классы, const

уж не знаю как реализовать и прошу у вас помощи, как мне задать информацию классу в char.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

#define N 3
class stars {
    char *name;
    float massa;
    double part;
    double count;
    
public:
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &stream, stars &o1);
    friend istream & operator>>(istream &stream, stars &o1);
    friend void shapka(void);
    friend void linebuild(void);
    friend int isvalid(int a, int b);
    stars() { massa = 0; count = 0; }
    stars(char *a, float &b, double &c, double &d);
    void setall(char *a, float b, double, double);
    stars(char* a, float & b, unsigned int & c, float & d);
    void getall(char *a, float& b, double &c, double &d);
    void showall(void);
    stars operator = (stars &o1);
    int   operator == (stars &o1);
    stars operator + (stars &o1);

};
void linebuild(void) {
    cout << "\n|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
}
void shapka(void)
{
    cout << "_______________________________________________________________\n";
    cout << "|         Буддистские монастыри Японии периода Нара           |\n";
    cout << "|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
    cout << "|  Название  | Школа | Количество монахов | Площадь земли(га) |\n";
    cout << "|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
}
void stars::setall(char *a, float b, double c, double d) {
    strcpy(name, a);
    massa = b;
    part = c;
    count = d;
}
ostream & operator<<(ostream &stream, stars &o1) {
    shapka();
    stream << "|" << setw(10) << o1.name << "  |  ";
    stream << setw(5) << o1.massa << "|";
    stream << setw(18) << o1.part << "  |";
    stream << setw(17) << o1.count << "  |" << endl;
    linebuild();
    return stream;
}
istream & operator>>(istream &stream, stars &o1) {
    cout << "Название, Школа, Количество монахов, Площадь земли: \n";
    stream >> o1.name;
    stream >> o1.massa;
    stream >> o1.part;
    stream >> o1.count;
    return stream;
}
stars::stars(char *a, float &b, unsigned int &c, float &d) {
    name = new char[strlen(a) + 1];
    strcpy(name, a);
    massa = b;
    part = c;
    count = d;
}
int isvalid(int a, int b) {
    if (((a > N - 1) || (a < 0)) || ((b > N - 1) || (b < 0)))
    {
        cout << "Ошибка! Экземпляра с таким индексом не существует.\n";
        getch();
        return -1;
    }
    else if (a == b)
    {
        cout << "Ошибка! Экземпляр не может быть записан сам в себя.\n";
        getch();
        return -2;
    }
    return 0;
}

stars stars::operator + (stars &o1) {
    stars tr;
    int i, j;
    delete[] tr.name;
    tr.name = new char[strlen(name) + strlen(o1.name) + 2];
    strcpy(tr.name, name);
    strcat(tr.name, o1.name);
    tr.massa = massa + o1.massa;
    tr.part = part + o1.part;
    tr.count = count + o1.count;
    return tr;
}

int stars::operator == (stars &o1) {
    if (count != o1.count) { cout << "Данные экземпляры класса не равны."; getch(); }
    else if (ceil(massa) != ceil(o1.massa)) { cout << "Данные экземпляры класса не равны."; getch(); }
    else if (ceil(part) != ceil(o1.part)) { cout << "Данные экземпляры класса не равны."; getch(); }
    else if (strcmp(name, o1.name) != 0) { cout << "Данные экземпляры класса не равны."; getch(); }
    else cout << "Экземпляры класса равны."; getch();
    return 0;
}

stars stars::operator = (stars &o1) {
    delete[] name;
    name = new char[strlen(o1.name) + 2];
    if (!name) {
        cout << "Ошибка! Память не выделена.";
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(name, o1.name);
    massa = o1.massa;
    part = o1.part;
    count = o1.count;
    return o1;
}
void stars::showall(void) {
    cout << name << " ";
    cout << massa << " ";
    cout << part << " ";
    cout << count << " ";
}
void stars::getall(char * a, float &b,double &c, double &d)
{
    delete[] a;
    a = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    strcpy(a, name);
    b = massa;
    c = part;
    d = count;
    cout << a << " ";
    cout << b << " ";
    cout << c << " ";
    cout << d << " ";
    cout << "\n";
}
void system(){

}
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    char *n;
    stars  t;
    double s;
    double h;
    short i, k;
    unsigned int s1;
    short q, q1;
    stars ob1;
    ob1.setall("v", 220, 368.8, 22);// ЗДЕСЬ РУГАЕТСЯ
    
    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: Почитайте о том что такое [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Ну, тут-то все просто: вы объявляете

```
void setall(char *a, float b, double, double);
```

т.е. говорите тем самым - я буду в функции менять содержимое строки `a` (будете ли вы это делать на самом деле - не важно). Но менять простой строковый литерал, который вы передаете - нельзя. Вот компилятор и не позволяет вам его передать в функцию.

```
void setall(const char *a, float b, double, double);
```

Вот в такую - разрешит.

Но это далеко не все неприятности. Например, рассмотрим простейший пример

```
stars tr;
int i, j;
delete[] tr.name;
```

В первой строке создается объект, у которого `name` никак не инициализируется -имеет случайное значение. А в третьей вы пытаетесь освободить память по этому случайному адресу.

И это не единственная ошибка. Пересмотрите внимательно свой код, в плане использования памяти - типа, "а не может ли здесь быть чтение в никуда" или "а мне точно хватит места для записи"?

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Если вам не трудно ответить еще на один вопрос, то пожалуйста помогите. В примере мне дали присваивание данным способом                                                      
      `stars obj[N] = { stars("Т",22,368.8,32),stars("С",50,54.7,34),stars("Д",10,12.2,55) };`                                                                                                         
    , но как всегда ничего не работает, не могли бы Вы объяснить, что здесь не так.

Comment: Потому что в конструкторе вы описали ссылки (`float &b` и иже с ней), а передаете литералы - раз. Потому что вы описали 2 конструктора с довольно близкими типами, и ни один под ваши литералы не проходит - два (не считая того, что второй конструктор объявлен, но не определен). Переделайте свой конструктор в `stars(const char* a, float  b, unsigned int  c, float  d);` и расставьте в инициализации правильно параметры - а то у вас `float`, скажем, 22, а `unsigned int` - 368.8...